# Why does stencil version 1+ removes type attribute from HTML button?

Tags: javascript, ionic4, web-component, stenciljs, stencil-component

I have recently update stencil core version to latest i.e 1.3.2

After updating there is a weird issue, which i am not sure is a bug or intended behavior. I read the changelog but could not find anything related to the issue

Stencil removes "type" attribute from HTML buttons in the final output created from jsx inside the render function. **This only happens if the attribute value is "submit"**, It remain intact if the value is "button"

**JSX:**

```
render() {
    return (
      <div class="dialog-footer">
        <button class="ui button blue" disabled={false} type="submit">save</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**After build:**

```
 render() {
        return (h("div", { class: "dialog-footer" },
                h("button", { class: "ui button blue", disabled: false, type: "submit" }, "save")));
    }
```

**Final output**

```
<div class="dialog-footer">
  <button class="ui button blue">Save Settings</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug where some attributes are not rendered, mostly default values (like `<input type="text" />`).

As a workaround you can set the property instead of the attribute:

```
<button ref={el => el.type = 'submit'} />
```

Related issues:

- [rendering `attribute={0}` results in no attribute on the rendered element](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/1780)
- [Still seeing falsey JSX issues with empty string](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/1824)
- [Stencil removes type attribute from button](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/1889)